# xclip and trailing spaces

Tags: bash, carriage-return, xclip

I use xclip to get my current path in my clipboard this way :

```
pwd | xclip -selection c
```

it almost works : if you paste (ctrl v) in an empty file, you will see that there is a trailing carriage return. It's very annoying since if you past in a term, then it immediately executes your expression, even if you did not finished to type.

The problem is the same with :

```
echo "titi" | xclip -selection c
```

- is it due to xclip ?
- Why xclip would add a trailing carriage return ?
- Is there a carriage return at the end of every string in bash ?

Comment: It's because you're using `echo`, that adds a trailing newline. To fix this, you may use `echo -n` or, much better, use `printf`: `printf '%s' "$PWD" | xclip -selection c`.

Comment: Great ! so I am now looking for an alias such as 

alias xclip='xclip -selection c'
but which would work with 
pwd | xclip 
and 
xclip myfile.txt

Comment: I tried different solutions without success because the difference between printf '%s' `pwd`  and pwd | printf '%s'  ??

Comment: If you want such an alias, `alias myxclip='printf %s "$(< /dev/stdin)" | xclip -selection c'`.

Comment: excellent, it works, it will be long before I understand your syntax, many thanks !

Comment: Seriously helpful

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the commands that add a new line character (`\n`) at the end of their output, `pwd` is one of these, as is `echo` (without `-n`).

One solution is to strip the new line out of the text before sending it to `xclip`, for instance :

`pwd | tr -d "\n" | xclip -selection c`

Here we use the `tr` tool to remove the new line.

Answer (score 0):

Gniourf_gniourf answer is perfect : in .bahs_aliases :

```
alias myxclip='printf %s "$(< /dev/stdin)" | xclip -selection c'
```

then you can redirect the standard output to your clipboard :

```
pwd | myxclip
ls -al | myxclip
...
```